# FFMPEG performance when reading directly from s3 vs local

Tags: performance, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I have a usecase where I need to transcode a s3 file. I have two options

Option a : Download the file to local, then run ffmpeg on it

Option b : Provide a presigned URL as ffmpeg input eg - 
"./ffmpeg -loglevel debug -y -i "https://mybucket/key?signedParams"  -threads 0 -map_chapters -1 -f mp4 -movflags faststart -map 0:0 -acodec libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b:a 48k -sn -vn /output.mp4"

I tried running both and comparing the time but I don't see any much performance improvement in #b as compared to #a.

I have 2 questions

1. Is #b is better in performance than #a? Or both of them are same?
2. In case of #b does ffmpeg wait for complete download and then start transcoding or it start downloading and transcoding simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried running both and comparing the time but I don't see any much performance improvement in #b as compared to #a.

Your bottleneck is probably in the transcoding then.

> Is #b is better in performance than #a? Or both of them are same?

I imagine streaming the input (when compatible) would be better performance.  Certainly less work to do.  But, if downloading that file in the first place isn't the bottleneck then it isn't going to matter a ton.

> In case of #b does ffmpeg wait for complete download and then start transcoding or it start downloading and transcoding simultaneously?

It will transcode as it is downloading/streaming.

Comment: Also do you know if only presigned urls are allowed as input to ffmpeg or we can provide s3 key url as well?

Comment: @user1147070 FFmpeg doesn't know about the S3 API, so only presigned URLs are usable.